# Adding a UIView above the current view

Tags: uiview, view

Edit: I've added the view, now I just need to know how to remove it with the close button :|

[image: 1]

Comment: Just so you know, the Flickr image you embedded is "currently unavailable."

Comment: Thanks, but that's just a prototype for learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press close , you call `[your_small_view removeFromSuperview];` on that button action , of course if you were talking about ios.